# Why Is The "while" Function For C# Crashing Game Engine?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a game made in Unity Engine.
For Movement, I have used vector2. But for vector2, you need to spam the buttons in order for the player to move. So i tried "while" function to loop the process. Here is the main code

```
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
    {
        i = 5;

    }

    //test

    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.W))
    {
        i = 1;
    }

    
   

    while(i !=1)
    {
        rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * JumpForce);
    }
```

However, when I run it the engine crashes. Why?
Just to let you know, there are no compiler errors.

Comment: Where is the code that changes _i_ inside that loop? Once entering the loop it continues to run forever, until whatever rb.AddForce does exaust stack or heap memory

Comment: (I don't know Unity but know general of game engines concept) what do you mean by "main code" if it's somewhere in `Update` then `Update` is already inside while loop ... so you have to do something that should happend beteewn now and last `Update` call and not block inside `Update`

Comment: because it never ends ....

Comment: ... so prolly `if` instead `while` should be ok

Comment: Those three statements (2x `if`, 1 `while`) are not all running at the same time all the time, but one after the other. The third one is the while-loop, which never finishes

Comment: `you need to spam the buttons in order for the player to move.` -> well have you tried simply using `Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)` instead which stays `true` as long as the button stays pressed?

Answer (score 1):

In Unity, the physics movement should be done in `FixedUpdate`, and input checking in `Update`. Something like this:

```
[SerializeField] private Rigidbody _rb;
[SerializeField] private float _jumpForce;

private bool _addForce;

private void Update()
{
    _addForce = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W);
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (_addForce) _rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * _jumpForce);
}
```

If you add a `while` in the `Update`, it will stuck in that frame, freezing the main loop, and the engine can't poll for new inputs, so your `Update` can't continue.

Comment: I tried your code, but The player won't move when "W" pressed.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote `OnUpdate()` instead of `Update()`. I played with Flax Engine before I wrote the example code :)
Edited.

Answer (score 0):

The repeated addforces might be a bit much for the PC.

Do this:

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
{
    rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * JumpForce);
}
```

This way it only moves when key is being held.